# What is the product of the following series of reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, erratum

> [image].

The answer given to this question is [image].

This is how I attempted solving the problem[image].

Considering that my answer and the author's answer is differing only by a methyl group, is this a publishing error or am I wrong somewhere?

---

*Himanshu pandey*, Advanced Problems in Organic Chemistry, 9th edition page 219 question number 4

Comment: Yes, it is an error and your answer is correct. I have the same book and I have also got the same answer as you

Comment: It is evident from counting the carbons and the types of reactions performed that they are missing a carbon. Nice work, anyway.

Comment: Not sure there is much further to be said, maybe @ringo could convert that into an answer? Anyway there's an anon VTC flag on this, and it doesn't constitute homework, and indicating that is the purpose of this comment. Ugh, awkward.